# Подскажите почему функция вывела NaN

Tags: javascript

```js
function calcD(a, b, c) {
   return b*b - 4*a*c;
}

calcD(-4, 2, 1);
alert(calcD());
```

Почему функция вывела NaN по идеи как я понимаю она должна была вывести число ?

```js
function calcD(a, b, c) {
   return b*b - 4*a*c;
}

var test = calcD(-4, 2, 1);
alert(test); // 20
```

А вот так вывела число ?

Comment: Вы запускаете функцию два раза: в первый раз вы передаёте ей числа и она возвращает число, но вы его никак не используете и просто выбрасываете; второй раз вы не передаёте в него ни единого числа, без чисел она естественно считает что попало и выдаёт NaN, который и выводится через alert

Answer (score 5):

[Window.alert(message)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) 
message это опциональная (необязательная) **строка** текста, которую вы хотите отобразить в диалоговом окне, или же объект, который **будет преобразован в строку** и отображен.

Ну а самое главное - Вы не передаете в функцию параметры. Т.е. вызываете calcD(undefined, undefined, undefined)